# Auto generate SSRS report daily - excel format - report server

Tags: ssrs-2008, business-intelligence

I've been tasked with creating a SSRS report that will automatically run every day @ 2 PM and dump the results via excel format into a designated folder on the report server.  Can someone point me in the right direction!?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

When you **Deploy** your report to the **Report Server**, you can set up a **Windows File Share** Subscription to place a file in the folder you need.

[image]

The folder's **permissions** will be your nemesis.